# Property is not defined for type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Double] when using Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have an expression that I am trying to build using a parameter and its value.
The value within the parameter is a member expression object.

```
//targetFieldExp - MemberExpression
//targetFieldExp.Type - 'System.Nullable`1[System.Double]'"
//targetFieldExp.Member.Name - 'quantity'

var param = Expression.Parameter(targetFieldExp.Type, "blah");
var prop = Expression.Property(param, targetFieldExp.Member.Name); //error occurs here
var myConstant = Expression.Constant((double?)5);
return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(prop, myConstant));
```

My issue is the moment I try to create the Expression Property I get "Property is not defined for type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Double] when using Expressions"

I have also tried the statement below with no luck:

```
Expression.Property(param, (PropertyInfo)targetFieldExp.Member)
```

Comment: Can you please tell what do you want to achieve by that code?

Comment: @GeorgeKarlinzer Eventually I want to return an Expression using Expression.Equals using that prop variable and another expression constant.

Comment: The obvious problem is that you're trying to get some property from value of type ```double?```.

Comment: Do I understand your problem correctly: you want to build an expression, that would grab some property of type ```double?``` from a parameter of type ```targetFieldExp.GetType()```?

Comment: @GeorgeKarlinzer yes correct

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]?

Comment: You current code tries to generate something like `t => t.quantity.blah` where `quantity` is `double?`. It is very unclear what you are actually trying to do.  What is `targetFieldExp`, why are you trying to turn it into a parameter?

Comment: @GuruStron blah would just be the name of the parameter while quantity is the property name and quantity is of type double?

Comment: @TheProgrammer oh, sorry, a bit misread the code, you are trying to generate `blah => blah.quantity` where `blah` is property type of `quantity`.

Comment: @TheProgrammer: The array of ParameterExpression objects has to be passed to `Expression.Lambda` and it looks like you haven't done so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MemberExpression.Type` will return the [type of the property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression?view=net-7.0#properties):

> Gets the static type of the expression that this Expression represents.
> (Inherited from Expression)

if you need the type declaring it use `MemberExpression.Member.DeclaringType;`:

```
var memberDeclaringType = targetFieldExp.Member.DeclaringType;
var param = Expression.Parameter(memberDeclaringType, "blah");
var prop = Expression.Property(param, targetFieldExp.Member as PropertyInfo); // todo - validate is not null
```

Comment: So in my case targetFieldExp is the MemberExpression, so I would be using that to get the declaring type correct?

Comment: @TheProgrammer yes, you will use `targetFieldExp` instead of `memberExpression`, fixed the typo.

Comment: Thank you that got me pass that error! I will probably need to debug more but I am getting "The LINQ expression 'blah' could not be translated. When returning the Lambda Expression to perform the final Equals.

Comment: Take off the `.Name`, it's better to work with the MemberInfo (PropertyInfo).

Comment: @BenVoigt agreed, was copied from the question.

Comment: @TheProgrammer was glad to help. If answer works or you - feel free to mark it as accepted one. As for not translated I would argue it should be another question with full [mre] provided. It seems that you are working with EF Core and there can be multiple issues (lie you are using a new parameter which is not present in the expression parameters, parameters are matched by instance, not name)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to build an expression, that would grab some property from some parameter that you would pass later. That expression would look like that:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
var prop = Expression.Property(param, "NameOfYouProperty");
```

For example, if you want to get Name from parameter of type Person:

```
class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "p");
var prop = Expression.Property(param, nameof(Person.Name));
```

Basically you have to know parameter type and property name.

Full example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "x");
        var prop = Expression.Property(param, nameof(Person.Name));
        var getProp = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person,string>>(prop, param).Compile();

        
        var person = new Person();
        person.Name = "asd";
        
        Console.WriteLine(getProp(person));
    }
    
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}   
    }
}
```

Comment: I get that I would need grab a property my problem is, as in your example Expression.Property(param, nameof(Person.Name)). Person.Name is not defined for type string

Comment: what do you mean by _Person.Name is not defined for type string_?

Comment: That is essentially the error I am getting in my case, except for mine my type is a nullable double

Comment: please provide some code, because my solution is working: https://dotnetfiddle.net/guR3lc. You can show the exact class that you want to retrieve property from?

Comment: Something on the lines of this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PSog9v

Comment: @TheProgrammer you have an error in your example, instead of `var getProp = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person,bool>>(Expression.Equal(prop, Expression.Constant((double?)5))).Compile();`, should be `var getProp = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(Expression.Equal(prop, Expression.Constant(5.5, typeof(double?))), param).Compile();`